# How to learn the DOM API / Which parts of the DOM API are important to learn?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I'm not totally new to web development or anything...reasonably experienced with it actually, to an extent.

But I had only ever used `window` and `document` in the past, amongst what I have now learned are [many DOM API interfaces.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference)

This is unnerving to me. In my quest to become a truly capable web developer, the extent of the DOM API has so far been the scariest thing I have encountered. It seems very difficult to me to get a real, strong grasp on it.

So I'm wondering, to developers more experienced with this, how did you learn it? Are there any excellent resources in particular, or an order you went in? Which parts of it are important? Which parts could easily be ignored completely?

I mean, even just in `document`, there are *many* methods I am totally unfamiliar with.

Comment: All parts of the DOM API are important to learn.

Comment: Most of the many methods will be irrelevant for you - but whenever you do something cumbersome, you might check whether there is a programmatic way in the DOM api. Most important (next to `Document`) to you will be `Node`, `Element`, `Event`, `CSSStyleDeclaration` and the element-specific classes (`HTMLInputElement` etc)

Comment: This is pretty much unanswerable for *any* API or system. There will always be many more methods than you'll ever use in any system; which ones are important to you is discovered through practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following diagram provides an overview of the DOM core interfaces with the most basic attributes and operations. As suggested by Bergi, the most important interfaces are `Node`, `Document` and `Element`. However, when you have to access/manipulate a specific HTML element (e.g. `table`) you should also look up the interface of such a specific element (e.g.[HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement)) for the availability of useful attributes and operations (e.g. `insertRow`).

[image]

Comment: Care to share from where this document came?

Comment: I made it myself for teaching a lecture on the DOM.

Comment: Unfortunately it's wrong. [`ProcessingInstruction`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1004215813) does not inherit from the `CharacterData` interface.

Comment: You refer to the obsolete DOM3, while I'm talking about DOM4.